# MySQL: Proportionally add values to column

Tags: mysql

I have a table ("user_credits") like the following:

[image: table]

I'm looking for a query that allows to increase or decrease the number of total number of credits by X value, and add that value proportionally to each user credits, depending on their share of the total credits pool. (sum of credits column)

Any ideas?

Would this be a good solution? is there a better way to do it?

```
UPDATE user_credits 
SET credits = (
    SELECT (credits + X /(SELECT SUM(credits) 
                          FROM (SELECT * FROM user_credits) AS MYALIAS) * credits))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the nested subqueries. You can join with a query that gets the sum.

```
UPDATE user_credits
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(credits) AS total
            FROM user_credits)
SET credits = credits + X * credits / total
```